# Changing Mac OS X 10.6 Routing after VPN'd In

Tags: mac, vpn, routing, subnet

I have a coffee shop around the corner that I use to do some work when I want to get away from home. They offer free wi-fi and I then use my Mac 10.6 VPN to log into my work network. I have "Send all traffic over VPN connection" checked.

Before, their network was 10.0.0.x. I think they got a new router because it's now 192.168.2.x

However, this interferes with one of the subnets at work so now I can't visit 192.168.2.x at work.

So:

1) Office network: VPN gives IPs as 192.168.1.x. Another network is 192.168.2.x

2) Coffee network: Gives IPs as 192.168.2.x

I think if I set a route to send all 2.x traffic over the tunnel, it would blow up my routing to their system, right?

What should I do? I know the individual IPs of the servers I want... Maybe I could add each one, or can I add all of them minus the default gateway of their router? How do I set that up "temporarily" in my Mac?

Thanks!!

Comment: What is the subnet at the coffee shop?

Comment: 2) Coffee network: Gives IPs as 192.168.2.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added a simple route for one of the servers:

```
sudo route add -net 192.168.2.3 192.168.1.1 -interface
```

I guess I'll have to delete them after I disconnect otherwise once I get into the office it won't work...

Answer (score 3):

Whoever setup the VPN at work should have taken into account the frequency with which home and small office networks are using these address ranges by default and picked something that wouldn't conflict. If you have any direct access to this person, you should point out the oversight and ask that it be corrected.